# Sprite chasing player character in C#

Tags: c#, xna

I've looked at the ChaseAndEvade XNA code but as it is for a college project I must use some of the variables provided such as xPos and yPos rather than setting up a variable position.

I understand that I want to get the angle between the two vectors and then move forward in that direction. To my understanding this line of code would do just that.

```
position += direction * speed
```

However, how would I translate this to use xPos and yPos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have figured out the angle where you want to move relative to your screen coordinates, use:

```
xPos += Math.Cos(angle) * speed;
yPos += Math.Sin(angle) * speed;
```

Rember that angle has to be in radians. Multiply by Math.PI/180 to convert degrees to radians.

Comment: Or you can use `MathHelper.ToRadians` method.

Answer (score 1):

I assume if you are provided with two vectors, from which you create direction (as mentioned above) - Then you can simply add the x and y components of these vectors to xPos and yPos respectively!

Comment: I was planning on using a method in a line previous to it, and set up a method to calculate the direction.
    direction = CalcDirection(sourceXPos, sourceYPos, XPos, YPos);